# How to read specific sheet of an excel page using java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I want to read the 3rd sheet of an Excel spreadsheet and compare column D and F which contain Date. How to read these column and compare the same in Eclipse?

I would like to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question. You need to make it clearer, and show us your code

Answer (score 2):

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get third(numbering starts from 0) sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(2);

//Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

// Iterate through rows
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    // Index of column D is 3 (A->0, B->1, etc)
    Cell cellD = row.getCell(3);
    Cell cellF = row.getCell(5);

    Date dateD = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(cellD.getNumberValue()); 
    Date dateF = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(cellF.getNumberValue()); 

    // Your business logic continues....
}
```